# CCM instead of key wrap

Tags: encryption, key-management, aes, nist

Is there any instance of NIST or other encryption standards using AES-CCM to encrypt/authenticate key data?  I would like to use CCM over a keywrap function, but cannot find any precedent for this in cryptography standards.

If by design I guarantee that:
(1) Nonce data will not be reused
(2) The encrypting "transport" key will not be available to users for the encryption/decryption of non-key material

Are there any security vulnerabilities that make CCM a bad choice?

Comment: CCM is basically CTR with CBC-MAC. CTR provides confidentiality, and CBC-MAC, authenticity.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article on Key Wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Wrap) states:

> Goals (3) and (5) are particularly important, given that many widely deployed authenticated encryption algorithms (e.g., AES-CCM) are already sufficient to accomplish the remaining goals.

Which suggests AES-CCM is an adequate, if inefficient, solution.